# Instant Search: Function is not defined error

Tags: jquery

I have a built a basic php/MySQL search. My form uses a jQuery function that capture keystrokes and then performs an Ajax call that ultimately should give results that are relevant to the keystrokes. I am receiving an error of function `searchquery is not defined`. I then went and verified the syntax and it appears to me to be correct. [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/instant_search.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        (function($) {
            $.fn.searchquery = function() {
                $.post("insta_search.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}), function(output) {
                    $("#output").html(output);
                });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Search</h2>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for stuff" onkeydown="searchquery();"/>
        <input name="submit" value=">>" type="submit">
        <br />
        <div id="output" name="output">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     searchquery = function() {
        $.post("insta_search.php", {searchVal: $("input[name='search']").val()}, function(output) {
        $("#output").html(output);
        });
     };
});
```

A better approach would be **not to mix behaviour in content** (ie. do not mix js in html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name='search']").keydown(function(){
            $.post("insta_search.php", {searchVal: $("input[name='search']").val()}, function(output) {
                $("#output").html(output);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Search</h2>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for stuff" />
        <input name="submit" value=">>" type="submit">
        <br />
        <div id="output" name="output">
        </div>
```

Comment: I am getting a missing missing `;` by `$post` -> `});`. You can check the [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/instant_search.php) for the updated code

Comment: An extra parentheses was the problem

Comment: try removing the end parenthesis "{searchVal: searchTxt})" to "{searchVal: searchTxt}"

Comment: Mark as answer if that satisfies your question

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: searchTxt is not defined ".......Try using $("input[name='search']").val() instead of searchTxt

Comment: Works perfect! thank you for being proactive as problems appeared and your explanation.

Comment: it seems that `keydown` is a bit sketchy at times and does get all keys. Would it be better to set a timer that will trigger the keydown?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you had a redundant parentheses. Try this piece:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function($) {
    $.fn.searchquery = function() {
      $.post("insta_search.php", { searchVal: searchTxt }, function(output) {
        $("#output").html(output);
      });
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: $.post("insta_search.php", { searchVal: searchTxt }), function(out... You're closing the parentheses early, that is wrong